# Bash: Create hotkeys that move files to new directory?

Tags: bash

I have 1000 .jpg in directory 'A' that i need to move into 10 sub directories- 'A/1' through 'A/10'.

I have tried opening each image to view its contents before placing it into its sub-directory, and this process is very time consuming.  I am currently using finder on Mac but am attempting to find an easy way to do this, perhaps using the terminal.

Perhaps I can create hot keys 0-9 in mac preview that perform the bash mv command?

Comment: How exactly do you choose the destination directory?

Comment: i am annotating images for a machine learning algorithm that counts people in a crowd.  i am manually counting people in each image and then placing the image into a subdirectory corresponding to the number of counted people in the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Yeah, you're gonna love this.**

First off though you have to install iTerm2 which you can find here:

https://www.iterm2.com/

(I am not affiliated with them by the way)

iTerm2 has something called imgcat which can display an image in the terminal.

SO... open up the terminal and cd into the directory with all your images. (I am expecting 1000's of images in one folder here.)

THEN.... copy paste the below command and off you go. One of your images will be shown, you count them, type in the number of faces and hit enter. A directory is created with the number you typed in and then the image is moved there. The cycle repeats until you run out of images or you hit ctrl+c to quit.

if you do quit you can fire up the same script and continue where you left off... or add more images later :)

```
while read <&5 file; do echo -$file; imgcat $file; echo enter number of faces and the hit return.; read dir; mkdir $dir; mv $file $dir/; echo file $file copied to $dir/$file; done 5< <(find . -name '*.jp*g' -d 1 -print)
```

Same thing but in a more readable multiline format: (in case you want to whack it in a bash file (tedium.sh)

```
#!/bin/bash
while read <&5 file; do
    echo -$file;
    imgcat $file;
    echo enter number of faces and the hit return.;
    read dir;
    mkdir $dir;
    mv $file $dir/;
    echo file $file copied to $dir/$file;
done 5< <(find . -name '*.jp*g' -d 1 -print)
```

Comment: dude you are the f*ing man!  you literally saved me dozens and dozens of hours.  you know this is useful for anyone building their own large machine learning dataset- perhaps you should make a blog post about it!

Comment: @user7139513, dude you're welcome. I had a little time and was up for a challenge and I have prepped some datasets for this type of stuff before so I know the pain. I'm not much of a writer but I put it up at https://shabangweb.wordpress.com/2016/11/11/manually-processing-large-image-datasets-for-computer-vision-osx/. thanks for the support ;)

Comment: @user7139513, hey by the way. Do me a favour and mark the answer as accepted if it helped you out. Cheers.